# Dont want the extra message on click of Logout link in IE7

Tags: .net, vbscript, internet-explorer-7

I am trying to implement a code in which when user clicks on Logout link then a warning message has to be dispalyed to the user which is

```
     This will terminate the session and close the browser. Do you want to continue?
```

My website is running on IE6 and IE7. I have written below piece of code to implment it.

```
    Sub OnClickLogout() 
dim Answer, msg
Msg = "This will terminate the session and close the browser. Do you want to continue?"
Answer = MsgBox(Msg, vbYesNo + vbExclamation, "Warning")
if Answer = vbYes then
window.opener = "y"
window.parent.opener= "x"
     window.parent.close

end if
```

End Sub

My code is working perfectly fine in IE6 and my window is closing properly.
But in IE7 when I click on Yes button then I am getting an extra message as follows:

**"The web page you are viewing is trying to close the window. Do you want to close this window?"** with Yes and NO button

I dont want this extra message. I was getting the same message in IE6 also but for that I searched and checked that you have to set the `window.parent.opener = "Some String".` But this is not working in IE7 Could you all suggest me how to remove this message in IE7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this to avoid the Microsoft message in IE7:-

```
        window.opener="X"
        window.open "","_top"
        window.parent.close
```

I am sure it will definitely work.